# C++ Dynamic bool array causes crash

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, crash, boolean

Today I tried to program the Sieve of Eratosthenes and it works as far as it provides me with the prime numbers. But I have a problem with the dynamic array I don't understand.

First problem: As soon as I try to enter a "big" value for n (for example 120), the program crashes, it doesn't even allocate the memory.

Second problem: If I enter a value like 50 it is able to give out the correct prime numbers but crashes before it deletes the array.

Third problem: If I enter a very small value like 5 it is able to execute the entire program, it gives out the correct numbers and deletes the memory.

But I don't understand why it acts so differently. 120 boolean values can't crash my memory, at least I think so. And why isn't it able to delete an array of 50 values but is actually able to delete an array of 5 values?
Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
int n;
cin >> n;
n=n+1;
bool *feld = new bool[n];
for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
{
    int j=i*i;
    feld[j]=true;
    for(;j<n;j+=i)
        feld[j]=true;
}
for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    if(!feld[i])
        cout << i << endl;
    else;
delete[] feld;
feld = NULL;
```

Comment: Side note: Get used to use only English variable names, after the first time you tried to read Chinese source you'll appreciate this convention ;-)

Comment: I don't know about the main problem, but I did notice you have two separate `int i;`s in the `for` loops. Perhaps the compiler will optimize that out, but don't count on it. Consider declaring one `int i;` in the larger block so that you don't have to have two of them when you can just reuse the same value.

Comment: Consider writing the length of the array to the output, and then after that printing the key you're about to try to access. Perhaps then use cin or getchar to pause until you're ready. This might help you to see where the problem is.

Comment: Second side note: Using `std::vector`is better than dynamically allocating memory with `new`, mostly (but not only) because of exception safety concerns

Comment: @Hulk: Although `vector<bool>` can surprise you, if you're expecting it to behave like other flavours of vector. It's still (probably) what you want here, though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour true, should have mentioned these peculiarities as well...

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
int j=i*i;
feld[j]=true;
```

there is no check as to whether `j < n` so you are stomping over unallocated memory when `j >= n`.

Answer (score 5):

This code is wrong

```
bool *feld = new bool[n];
for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
{
    int j=i*i;
    feld[j]=true;
    ...
}
```

Suppose n == 10 and i == 9, then j == 81 but you only have 10 elements in your bool array.

This is how it works when you write bugged programs, sometimes it *seems* to work, it might even give the right answer, other times it will crash. This is a very important lesson, and you're actually lucky to have learned it early.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It's not just that `feld[j]=true;` is causing the error.

Also, you don't need that line at all before the loop.

because, it's the first case inside the loop.